# How to create a slider on an image

Tags: android

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

**The black rectangle is an image asset which i need to move left and right on related touch events/drags**

Being relatively new to Android , I am finding this difficult to implement.

So was hoping I could get some tips,guides,examples if there are any.

*EDIT:* 
I Have tried viewflipper but that is not what I need here,
I tried making a slider like a seek bar , but didn't work out.

Some one suggested that I use a framelayout over the main image to slide but I don't know how to do it.

So any help which will help me out here is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SeekBar because it suits your needs completely.

First create a drawable xml file named "rect_border.xml" in res/drawable folder with these contents:

```
// **EDITED**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:color="#000000"
        android:width="5dp"
        />
    // change the width to any value that suits your needs.
    // set the height property greater than your image height
    <size android:width="50dp" android:height="360px" />
</shape>
```

Then in your layout:

```
// **EDITED**
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:thumb="@drawable/rect_border"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tested it and I'm sure it's actually what you want (as described).
So what's the problem about the SeekBar?

Comment: the rectangle is bigger than background image as you can see in the image ive attached, also the rectangle is something i used for example i need to use a custome image instead of the rectangle

Comment: I edited my post and update both xml files. the only thing that you must change to get your desired result is the image height and border drawable height and of course you can set these values programmatically if you change your image drawable in the code.

Comment: thanks it works , only needed to change android:layout_height="300px" to wrap parent :)